# Importing csv file to SQL Server using python without an index

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I have imported a csv file into SQL Server with python but it is automatically inserting an index column as the first column. I have looked at other questions on SO regarding this issue and have tried things like index_col=false but the index still appears my code is as follows

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+UID+':'+PWD+'@'+DATABASE)

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\file.txt', chunksize=10000,index_col = False)

for i in data:
    i.to_sql('table1', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the `index = False` parameter to the `to_sql` method:

```
for i in data:
    i.to_sql('table1', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```